# How important it is to sync the timing for gnss and lidar in localization?

Tags: ros, localization, navigation, lidar, synchronization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have not synced the timing for gnss and lidar yet. Will it affect the localization accuracy a lot? I found gnss_pose is published based on the GPS time and ndt_pose is published based on the current timing. Why are they different?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/346730/how-important-it-is-to-sync-the-timing-for-gnss-and-lidar-in-localization?/) by [huifeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/46984/huifeng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2020-03-14

Post score: 1

Comment: What question is being asked is very unclear: it doesn't specify what "synced" means, nor does it define what "current timing" means, nor does it say *how* the data is being used/consumed.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Of course, GNSS and LiDAR should be time synchronized.

However, since Autoware Localization does not perform processing that requires strict time synchronization between GNSS and LiDAR, I think that even if the timing is not synchronized, it will not affect the position estimation much.

---

Originally posted by [Yamato Ando](https://answers.ros.org/users/43573/yamato-ando/) with karma: 231 on 2020-03-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't think that is important as much as long as GNSS Hz is below from a threshold such as 10Hz.
In my case when I increase the GNSS Hz, it created 30 seconds delays.

> I found gnss_pose is published based
> on the GPS time and ndt_pose is
> published based on the current timing.
> Why are they different?

I guess the fundamental reason for delay is your question, GPS time delays from the current_time when you incrase the speed of GNSS.

---

Originally posted by [yucedagonurcan](https://answers.ros.org/users/52554/yucedagonurcan/) with karma: 46 on 2020-03-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1